# converting flat txt file to nested xml

Tags: c#, xml

I need to convert text file with some conversion columns-elements to an nested xml file -
for example
txt flat file - `Name,Age,Street name,street number,city name`
conversion table-
flat file - `Name,Age,Street name,street number,city name`
conversion table -

```
Name-FullName
Age-Age
Street Name-AddressDetail-StreetName
Street Number-AddressDetail-StreetNumber
City Name-AddressDetail-CityName
```

xml file

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <Envelop>
       <FullName>Steve Mate</FullName>
       <Age>22</Age> 
       <AddressDetail>
               <StreetName>Rockford</StreetName>
               <StreetNumber>111</StreetNumber>
               <CityName>Alimena</CityName> 
       </AddressDetail>
    </Envelop>
```

What is the best way to implement it?
Can it be used with MVC?
Using `XElement`?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: One way to do that is to first parse the flat text file into a struct with the members corresponding to the text format, then serialize that one to xml (XmlSerializer), then run a XML Stylesheet (XSLT) to convert to the final format. Benefit: If your source format gets changed some day, you do not need to  look at all the code.

Comment: There are several questions in this question. You apparently have a "flat file" (with comma-separated values?) that you want to convert to a nested structure in XML. However, there's no indication of any research having been done, nor any attempts having been made. You mention `XElement` (I assumed that's what `xelemet` referred to). You also mention MVC, which is a framework for building HTML. Not sure what that has to do with anything.

Comment: I've helped OPs lots of times with similar issues.  Post sample of input file.  XElement is best way of achieving results.

Comment: thank you, I was on purpose giving a global question so I would get some variety of answers. I thought there is another way. xslt is something I never tried and will see the possibility, but xelemet is the most optimal, regarding mvc, I thought I can some how use it as a service that is basically getting input and create output , not related to any view, something that is more like a rest api type - post command related

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar a number of times.

There is no special trick to this. You will need to parse the input file to get the elements you need, and then you'll need to create an XML file with the data.

I don't know of any existing way to convert your particular text file format.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you

```cs
var lines = text.Split(new[] {"\r", "\n", "\r\n"}, 0);
var xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Envelop"));
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var values = line.Split('-');
    var parentNode = xDoc.Root;
    foreach (var value in values.Reverse().Skip(1))
    {
        var name = value.Replace(" ", "");
        var node = parentNode.Element(name);
        if (node == null)
        {
            node = new XElement(name);
            parentNode.Add(node);
        }
        parentNode = node;
    }
    parentNode.Value = values.Last();
}
```

- Split the text based on newlines.
- For each line, split it based on `-`
- Take the root the starting node
- For each value in the split line, skipping the first item...

  - Remove spaces (you can't have spaces in a node name).
  - Get the child node with that name
  - If it doesn't exist, create it.
  - Set the current parent as this node.
- Finally set the value of this node to the last item in the split values

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0fwzOk)

Output:

```xml
<Envelop>
  <FullName>FullName</FullName>
  <Age>Age</Age>
  <AddressDetail>
    <StreetName>StreetName</StreetName>
    <StreetNumber>StreetNumber</StreetNumber>
    <CityName>CityName</CityName>
  </AddressDetail>
</Envelop>
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the example, but what if my names are not similar(Name should be converted to FullName, is it posible to link field flat file to xml element name-> for example flat file field - Name , xml field name - FullName

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] containing this example. I suggest you create a new question for this, as your current question has been answered.